# React Native - gradle, manifest merge error

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio, expo

When trying to build my android react native app, im getting this error

```
Execution failed for task ':app:processReleaseMainManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : Attribute meta-data#org.unimodules.core.AppLoader#react-native-headless@value value=(org.unimodules.adapters.react.apploader.RNHeadlessAppLoader) from [:unimodules-react-native-adapter] AndroidManifest.xml:14:13-88
        is also present at [:expo-modules-core] AndroidManifest.xml:14:13-86 value=(expo.modules.adapters.react.apploader.RNHeadlessAppLoader).
        Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:value"' to <meta-data> element at AndroidManifest.xml:12:9-14:91 to override.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For now I know that in my case it is that I have conflict between two manifest files in node_modules folder:

```
> cd <YOUR_PROJECT_DIR>/node_modules   
> grep -r -i RNHeadlessAppLoader | grep AndroidMan

./expo-modules-core/android/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml:
android:value="expo.modules.adapters.react.apploader.RNHeadlessAppLoader" />
   
./@unimodules/react-native-adapter/android/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml:   
android:value="org.unimodules.adapters.react.apploader.RNHeadlessAppLoader"/>
```

**Solution**

- Add such `xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"` attribute to `<manifest>` tag in `<YOUR_PROJECT_DIR>/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml`
- Add such tag in `application` section of your manifest file

```
<meta-data
tools:replace="android:value" 
android:name="org.unimodules.core.AppLoader#react-native-headless"
android:value="org.unimodules.adapters.react.apploader.RNHeadlessAppLoader"/>
```

Comment: what did you do about it ? to make it bundle

Comment: still solving it :(

Comment: count me in as well, having similar error. I am trying to update my react native version to latest and getting this

Comment: This would resolve the merger conflict correctly, i just tested. But there are others build errors from the upgrade

Comment: It Solved the error, but it is now giving different permission errors

Answer (score 4):

Updating to last expo SDK seems to be working for me (version 43). Since they replaced the `react-native-unimodules` package with an `expo` one.

Comment: Yes it worked for me. If for some reason somebody cannot upgrade yet, please have a look at my solution (above or below)

Answer (score 0):

I have this issue when I updated from expo 42 to expo 43(I already ejected but still using some of the expo modules)

I uninstall `react-native-unimodules` and backup my android folder

then I run `expo prebuild`(it ended with some error but in the end, it works fine)

it will generate new android folder, then I slowly compare it with old android folder and add back whatever I need

and finally, I managed to get it running

expo 43 seems faster than expo 42, so I think it is worth the problem

Comment: I think its better not to run ```expo build```and to follow the steps written on expo to update to SDK 43